# Errors setting printer settings

Tags: powershell, printing

I am on a Server 2012 R2 system, I am working to migrate from a print server 2008 R2 environment over to my 2012 environment.

I have scripted the printer read from the old server and creation on the new server, but among other things I need to query certain settings and properties of the printer in the old environment and replicate it in the new.

For example - some of my queues on the old server are pointed to specific trays on a given printer - how do I query the old printer queue on the old server to get this information and set it in the new environment?

Additionally - Most of my printers are using the HP Universal Driver, some of them are color and we have manually set the "Device Type" to "Color". I can do a

```
$mysettings = get-printerproperty -computername <oldserver> -printername <queuename> -propertyname config:dynamicrender
```

and get the appropriate setting.  Yet, when I do a

```
set-printerproperty -computername <newserver> -printername <queuename> -propertyname config:dynamicrender -value $mysettings.value** - it doesn't work.
```

I get:

[image: Screen Shot of Error Message]

I've even tried some simple stuff like setting duplex unit to being installed - as seen in this [example from TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/20/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-fix-broken-printer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the PropertyName is case sensitive.  It worked when I capitalized the letters (C,D & R) shown below.

Set-PrinterProperty -PrinterName $Printer -PropertyName "Config:DynamicRender" -Value $DeviceType